# jquery: select list inside list

Tags: jquery

I have made a ul with a li-element and another ul. So, I want to fadeToggle the second ul if I click on the first li-element inside the first ul.

Html looks like this:

```
<ul id="timeline">
    <li class="year"></li>
        <ul class="eventList">
            <li class="event"></li>
            <li class="event"></li>
            <li class="event"></li>
            <li class="event"></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#timeline .event').hide();
    $('#timeline .year').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.eventList').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

However, it won't work. I don't know if I chose a wrong selector or not. I searched for errors but can't find any error.
Hopefully anyone of you could help me.

Live: http://cywa.eu/index.php/about/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.eventList').hide();
    $('.year').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.eventList').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this before, but the fadeToggle should only effect the clicked list, not every list on the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line `$('#timeline .event').hide();`

```
$(function() {
    $('.eventList').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#timeline.year').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.eventList').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

That line was causing every li of `.eventList` to be hidden.

Comment: It should be faded out by default, that's why I used .hide

Comment: See the updated code.. It will work.. Actually you were the child `li` and yu were toggling the hide of `ul` but the `li` were still hidden.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Instead of fadeOut it should be hided by default. Toggle didn't work anyway..